# Ubuntu can't connect internet without vpn

Tags: vpn, ubuntu-12.04

I'm new to the Linux world.

I set up Ubuntu 12.04 on my laptop. Everything had been fine before I installed and configured `forticlient SSL VPN` for my company's network. After this Ubuntu can't connect to the internet without that VPN connection.

What do you think is the problem? How can I connect to the internet without a VPN connection?

This is what `ifconfig` shows while not connected to vpn:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 64:31:50:99:39:ab  
      UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 68:a3:c4:78:86:32  
      inet addr:192.168.1.23  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::6aa3:c4ff:fe78:8632/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:255309 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:166003 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:295897343 (295.8 MB)  TX bytes:20157641 (20.1 MB)
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem lies in the /etc/resolv.conf file.
Forticlient doesn't do a good job in changing this file.

Change it to yours default values, then change in the file

```
forticlientsslvpn/helper/cleanup.linux.sh
```

the line

```
echo "restore /etc/resolv.conf" >> "$base/forticlientsslvpn.log"
```

to

```
echo "restore /var/run/resolvconf/resolv.conf" >> "$base/forticlientsslvpn.log"
```

It is working for me. My connection was slower but it is now back to normal.
I have Ubuntu 12.04 x64.

I uncompress the binaries on /opt/ so all is there

Mi .log file looks like

```
10/29/2013 13:42:34 [4168] starting pppd
10/29/2013 13:42:34 [4168] use tty:/dev/pts/2
10/29/2013 13:42:34 [4168] connecting to "hostXX":10443
10/29/2013 13:42:35 [4168] Got local address from ppp, interface will be  up
10/29/2013 13:42:39 [4168] ppp interface is up
10/29/2013 13:42:39 [4168] run_scutil XXX.XXX.106.77 10.42.4.165/255.255.255.255 0...
begin sysconfig linux
Generating pppd.resolv.conf...Done
nameserver  XX.XX.3.254
nameserver  XX.XX.4.11
server route 
interface ppp0
address XX.XX.101.73
delete route 1.1.1.1
Add route for XXX.XX.106.77(192.168.1.1)
route -n add -net XX.XX.4.165 netmask 255.255.255.255 gw XX.XX.101.73
```

I execute the binaries with sudo

Comment: You are using a relative path `forticlientsslvpn/helper/cleanup.linux.sh` maybe it would be better to describe what/where is it. Also I am wondering if content of a file with suffix `.log` is important for the behaviour of the software? Are you sure that changing content of the file `forticlientsslvpn.log` makes the difference?

Comment: I will answer the questkins in the last comment.

Comment: if [ -f "$base/resolv.conf.backup" ]; then
 echo "restore /var/run/resolvconf/resolv.conf" >> "$base/forticlientsslvpn.log"
 mv -f "$base/resolv.conf.backup" /etc/resolv.conf

There is the change, Do you think this dont make any change to the process of restore the resolv.conf archive?

Comment: `echo "restore /var/run/resolvconf/resolv.conf" >> "$base/forticlientsslvpn.log"` defines only what is written into `forticlientsslvpn.log`. If content of the `.log` file changes later behaviour of the software then it is OK. I am just wondering if this is really the case.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge resolvconf
sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart
```

http://community.spiceworks.com/topic/249180-ubuntu-server-12-04-no-internet-access-only-local-network#

Comment: You should explain what these commands do and why they're required. I'm inclined to believe this will fix his problem, but this answer could be much better.

Comment: I have faced same problem, it did helped me , Cheers

Answer (score 0):

VPN clients typically perform additions to the routing table, perhaps this is causing a problem.  Please post the output of ifconfig and netstat -r

Also, it is possible the network that you connected to used a proxy auto config file (PAC).  Perhaps it left your browser pointing to a proxy that is only accessible while connected to VPN?  Can you ping google.com when connected to the internet but not on VPN?

Comment: Hi @Gregg, 
It can't ping while doesn't connect vpn. And here is the other informations you want

netstat-r;
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
default         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 wlan0
link-local      *               255.255.0.0     U         0 0          0 wlan0
192.168.1.0     *               255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 wlan0

I have just edited original post with ifconfig because of it is too long

Comment: @Emre what do you mean by "doesn't ping"? If you can `ping 8.8.8.8` but `ping google.com` gives an `unknown` or `no route to host` error, it may be a DNS (nameserver) issue, where your VPN has stuck its own DNS servers in your network config and overwritten the non-VPN ones.